# Spring Roo "Base" URL

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I'm current building a fairly simple webapp using Spring Roo. It seems, however, that Spring apps by default deploy to "/{app name}", rather than "/" as the top level directory. That is, controllers are mapped by "/{app name}/person", rather than just "/person". After poking around considerably, I couldn't see where this would be fixed. Is it a setting somewhere?

Comment: Hi Aaron, as you are new to StackOverflow, I have a little hint for you: It is much more likely to get an answer fast, if you phrase your question as a question and if you include all names in it. So it would be better not to use "it" in the question, if possible. For example: `How can I change the Spring Roo "Base" URL?". Just a minor hint.

Answer (score 2):

The base path is defined by the application server, not the application itself.
In the pom.xml, overwrite the following plugins:

**maven-war-plugin - mvn package, mvn tomcat:run-war**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>ROOT</warName>
                <!-- exclude test files from war package -->
                <packagingExcludes>src/test/**</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**tomcat-maven-plugin - mvn tomcat:run**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**org.mortbay.jetty - mvn jetty:run**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4.v20111024</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Spring Roo application runs on Apache Tomcat, what you can do is to configure the Tomcat Root context.

You can do this in following ways.

1. Define a ROOT.xml context file in conf/Catalina/localhost
2. Name your webapp WAR “ROOT.war” or containing folder “ROOT”

More information can be found on the following link.

http://benhutchison.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/how-to-configure-tomcat-root-context/

Cheers!